# Are there various ways to use ~し?

Tags: usage, particles, conjunctions, particle-し

[The many ways to say “and” in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/474/the-many-ways-to-say-and-in-japanese) thread showed me that ～し, ～し can be used give reasons for something.

> この部屋は綺麗だし広いし間取りもいいから人気がある。
> This room is clean, wide and also good partition, so most of the people like it.
>   ねむいし仕事があるし (I'm sleepy, and I have work to do, and...[I really don't want to] [so I can't do what you're asking])

Seems kind of like ｘし、 ｙし　[だ]から　ｚ.

Can it be used the other way around: ｚから、 ｘし、 ｙし.　
For example, 今は休暇だから本を読んでるし、泳げるようになってるし、リラックスしてる。

And how about for just serial actions, for example in reply to something like 今日は何をしてる？

By the way, I don't remember seeing ～し in any textbooks so far, is it something you'd only use with friends?

Comment: is it ok to have multiple Shis in a sentence?  Thought it was one of those things you weren't suppose to use more than once in a sentence.

Comment: Tae Kim briefly covers 〜し in [Compound Sentences](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/compound#part7)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> 今は休暇だから本を読んでるし、泳げるようになってるし、リラックスしてる。

This is just my opinion for this particular sentence, but I'd go with the ～たり form here:

> 今は休暇だから本を読んで**たり**、泳げるようになって**たり**、リラックスしてる。

～し lists either actions or qualities, and while it resembles ～たり in that **it doesn't specify an order** in which the actions took place, it adds a **"not only, but also"** implication to it:

> 今年の夏は海に行った**し**、山にも行った。 This summer I went to the ocean, and **[not only that, I also went]** to the mountains.
>
> 荷物が多い**し**、雨も降ってきたし、どこかで休もうか。 We've a lot of luggage, and **[not only this, but]** it's started to rain, so shall we take a break somewhere?

(Above examples taken from page 198 of [初級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック](http://books.google.com/books?id=l-C4H2sBJlEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false))

In sentences like the second one above, where multiple ～し constructions are used to provide reasons, as you saw [in the other question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/474/the-many-ways-to-say-and-in-japanese), the last し can be replaced with から with hardly any change in meaning:

> 荷物が多いし、雨も降ってきた**から**、どこかで休もうか。 We've a lot of luggage, and it's started to rain, **so** shall we take a break somewhere?

～し can also get tacked onto the end of a sentence when that sentence provides justification for an immediately preceding statement:

> せっかくパリまで来たんだから、観光でもしよう。天気もいいし。 We've come all the way to Paris, so let's do some sightseeing. The weather's nice, too.
>
> このお店はすごくおいしいですよ。かなり安いですし。 The food here is amazingly good. And it's easy on the wallet, too.

～し can be used in both informal and formal settings (as seen in the second example immediately above, it can follow the polite form).

---

Mark Hosang kindly pointed out in the comments that in formal speech (and perhaps most commonly in written Japanese), the ～ます stem form of the verb する (し) is used as a transition between clauses, just as the ～て form (して) is used in spoken Japanese. From ALC:

> 上海の不動産価格は去年1年間で24％**増加し**、今では中国で1番高くなっています。
>
> Shanghai's real estate prices **increased** 24 percent over last year, and are now the highest in the country.

This is unrelated to the ～し form discussed in this question.

Comment: Just an addition, while not a Shi, in formal sentences shite becomes shi and will look very simliar to the Kara shi you have listed here. Just mentioning as it might be a point of confusion.

Comment: @Mark: That's a good point; I'll edit my answer to make note of it.

Comment: Surely would have read it as the other し. Thanks for pointing that out guys.

Comment: This was a very informative answer. It has helped me better organise the usages of 〜し in my head. Thanks @Derek!