# Help understanding sentence with と

Tags: grammar, particle-と

From prologue of 義妹生活 novel

> ...ひとえに親父が「元気」だったから。よくもまああんな目に遭いながら再婚なんてする気になったと、心の底から尊敬する。物心ついたときから喧嘩ばかりの両親を見て育ってきた俺は、親父に離婚すると聞かされたときはそりゃそうだろうなと思ったし、自分の甲斐性の無さのせいだと頭を下げられたときは、いやいや母親の浮気が原因って知ってる**しと冷めた気持ちで聞いていた**。

I understand that this し is reason marker and と is quotative but I struggle to understand the rest of the sentence. I think this part can be rewritten as

> 自分の甲斐性の無さのせいだと頭を下げられたときは、「いやいや母親の浮気が原因って知ってる**し気にしないでくれ!」と言って、親父の言うことを冷めた気持ちで聞いていた。**

Is that right?

Edit:

Based on @EddieKal comments, it seems to me that という sometimes gets shortened to と when placed before 気持ち. Does it apply to other nouns? What is the difference between と and という in this context?

Comment: The way I parse it is: [[いやいや母親の浮気が原因ってことを知ってるしと]冷めた気持ちで]聞いていた。「いやいや母親の浮気が原因ってことを知ってるしと」describes 気持ち

Comment: @EddieKal Interesting, so sometimes という can be contracted to と when describing a noun?

Comment: That's my understanding. Random examples culled from the web: 「男性が言う「距離を置く」という言葉には、単純に別れたいと気持ちだけでなく、様々な心理が隠されています。」「自分を強く見せたいと気持ちが引き締まった状態です。 」

Comment: 「いやいや〜知ってるし」と（思いながら）

Comment: @EddieKal - 自分を強く見せたいと modifies 引き締まった, not 気持ち. Something like 思って or 思い (verb) is omitted after と. I don’t know how 単純に別れたいと気持ちだけでなく、様々な心理が隠されています is supposed to be parsed. It sounds simply incorrect. It should be 別れたいという気持ち.

Comment: @aguijonazo Hmm, I see. Maybe I've held と to be more versatile than it really is...

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1361/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quotative-と with implied **思って/考えながら**, etc. (But not 言って; you cannot say something while listening...)

> いやいや母親の浮気が原因って知ってるしと冷めた気持ちで聞いていた。
> I was listening (to dad's apology) with a turned-off/sober mind, (secretly) thinking "No, I know it was because of my mother's cheating".

気にしないでくれ is not implied. He just *thought* this. He doesn't seem to be willing to support either of his parents anyway.