# How would you say "Something isn't X, but isn't Y as well."

Tags: grammar, syntax

I'm currently practicing to use japanese adjectives by writing down sentences with antonym pairs, and I came up with the following sentence.

"My room isn't dirty, but it isn't clean as well."

Unfortunately I find it difficult to find an appropiate grammatical structure which can be used to translate this sentence. I have been looking around the internet for a bit, but I can't seem to find a satisfactory answer. The closest I got to an answer was [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/how-to-say-also-or-too) post, but it isn't really usable in this context. Can somebody help me to find an suitable grammatical pattern for this particular sentence?

Comment: Thanks for all the useful answers! Learned som new grammar structures in the process :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some phrases. For example, "Aではないが、Bでもない", "Aではない、でもBでもない", "AでもBでもない".

Your sentence is translated like "汚くないが、きれいでもない", "汚くない、でもきれいでもない", "汚くもきれいでもない", etc.

Comment: +1. I would highlight the way to attach も after a negative い-adjective (**なくも**). Besides, how would you say "as well"? My hunch is to go with くもある/でもある, but it sounds like using である, which bears a specific (and rather tough) intonation...

Comment: Yes, it is 汚くもない, not 汚いでもない. I used でもない to include the nuance of "as well".

Answer (score 3):

A fancy way to say it could be :

> ...汚いわけではないけど、きれいでもないです。
>   It's not that it's dirty, but it is not clean either.

A more simple way :

> ...きれいでもない、汚いでもない。
>   It's neither clean nor dirty.

Comment: `汚いわけないないけど` ← 「ないない」って、なにかの書き間違いではありませんか？　`きれいでもない、汚いでもない` ← 通常は、「きれいでもな**く** 、汚**く**もない」になると思うのですが、いかがでしょう？

Comment: @Chocolate 重複した「ない」は気づかなかった、ありがとうございました。　「きれいでもなく」はしゃべる時も使いますか？「きれいでもない」はもっと聞く気がしてたけど、間違っている可能性も高いです。

Comment: はい、確かに、「し」がついて、「きれい**でもないし** 、汚くもない。」なら、しゃべるときによく使うと思います。「でもないし～」は、「でもなく～」より口語的だと思います。

Answer (score 2):

I would go with 「～ないけど、～でもない/～くもない」. Works in the majority of cases:

部屋はきれいじゃないけど、汚くもない。
My room is not clean, but it isn't dirty either.

外はうるさくないけど、静かでもない。
Outside is not loud, but it isn't quiet either.