# How to coordinate two noun clauses (の-clauses)?

Tags: grammar

> He likes to eat pasta and to drink beer.
>
> 彼はパスタを食べるのとビールを飲むのが好きです。
>
> 彼はパスタを食べるのやビールを飲むのが好きです。
>
> 彼はパスタを食べてビールを飲むのが好きです。
>
> 彼はパスタを食べたりビールを飲むのが好きです。
>
> 彼はパスタも食べるがビールも飲むのが好きです。
>
> 彼はパスタも食べればビールも飲むのが好きです。
>
> 彼はパスタも食べビールも飲むのが好きです。

Is there any difference in meaning? Are some of these sentences more formal or more colloquial, more or less common?

Comment: You have already answered your own question... What's the problem?

Comment: There are all these alternatives. It's a bit confusing. 
Are they all correct? 
Is there any difference between all these forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私ならこう言います。

> 彼が好きなのはパスタとビール。

の-clauses, to drink and to eat are all omitted.

I checked the given seven Japanese sentences from the standpoint of whether they are natural or not, and judged them and gave recommended samples and the reason if necessary as follows:

1. 〇彼はパスタを食べるのとビールを飲むのが好きです。
2. 〇彼はパスタを食べるのやビールを飲むのが好きです。
3. ×彼はパスタを食べてビールを飲むのが好きです。
   →【a recommended sample】彼はパスタを食べてビールを飲むのが好きです。その逆｛ぎゃく｝の、先｛さき｝にビールを飲んで後｛あと｝でパスタを食べるのはダメです。
   （【the reason of ×】「て」には順序｛じゅんじょ｝あるいは条件｛じょうけん｝を表｛あらわ｝すニュアンスがある。）
4. ×彼はパスタを食べたりビールを飲むのが好きです。
   →彼はパスタを食べたりビールを飲んだりするのが好きです。
   （「～たり」は繰｛く｝り返｛かえ｝して使｛つか｝うことが一般的｛いっぱんてき｝です。）
5. ×彼はパスタも食べるがビールも飲むのが好きです。
   →彼は固｛かた｝いパスタも食べるがやわらかいパスタも食べるのがすきです。
   （共通｛きょうつう｝要素｛ようそ｝がないと、「が」は不｛ふ｝自然｛しぜん｝です。）
6. ×彼はパスタも食べればビールも飲むのが好きです。
   →彼は日本酒｛にほんしゅ｝も飲めばビールも飲むのが好きです。
   （共通｛きょうつう｝要素｛ようそ｝がないと、「れば」は不｛ふ｝自然｛しぜん｝です。）
7. ×彼はパスタも食べビールも飲むのが好きです。
   →彼はパスタも食べビールも飲み更｛さら｝に〇〇〇も好きです。
   （２つの行為｛こうい｝では「も」は物｛もの｝足｛た｝りない。）

Comment: Thank you for answering, mackygoo. This literally means "it's pasta and beer what he likes", is it right? 
Is there any difference in usage (more/less common, more formal/colloquial) between all those sentences?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. 彼はパスタを食べるのとビールを飲むのが好きです。
> 2. 彼はパスタを食べるのやビールを飲むのが好きです。
> 3. 彼はパスタを食べてビールを飲むのが好きです。
> 4. 彼はパスタを食べたりビールを飲むのが好きです。
> 5. 彼はパスタも食べるがビールも飲むのが好きです。
> 6. 彼はパスタも食べればビールも飲むのが好きです。
> 7. 彼はパスタも食べビールも飲むのが好きです。

You're interested in connecting two *noun* clauses, right? However, technically speaking, only Sentence 1 and Sentence 2 have two noun clauses. Sentence 3-7 each has only one noun clause (because there is only one の in each sentence). In other words, in Sentences 1 and 2, you are nominalizing two verbs independently first, getting two noun phrases, and then joining the two using と or や. On the other hand, in Sentences 3-7 you are first connecting two verbs using て, たり, etc., and then nominalizing it all at once using a single の. That's a large difference.

When you say "He likes to eat pasta and to drink beer," you are presenting the two actions more or less independently, right? Then the normal translation of this would be either Sentence 1 or Sentence 2. As for the difference between と and や, please see this: [The many ways to say "and" in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/474/5010)

Sentence 3 means he likes only one thing, "eating pasta and then drinking beer". Maybe eating pasta alone or drinking beer alone is not what he likes.

Sentence 4 is close to "He likes doing things like eating pasta and drinking beer."

Sentences 5-7 are grammatical but uncommon and nuanced. Basically they are similar to Sentence 3 in that he only likes one thing, but sounds more emphatic about the two actions happening simultaneously. These sentences imply ordinary people usually don't have pasta and beer at the same time, which I don't think is true.