# Japanese equivalent to 'and/also' for part-sentences?

Tags: grammar, nuances, particles

I know of using と for noun & noun phrases, て-form to connect sentences
Perhaps when speaking English you might suddenly remember something and go 'Oh! *And* (whatever you remembered).

Another example may be, say, listing, but with something in brackets/aside from the normal list. 'Mum, Dad, Brother (And a cat!)

Maybe you're leaving home for school and your mom may call 'And don't forget to eat your fruit!', or something similar.

Is there a word or particle you would use independently in these circumstances? 
I have seen [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/474/the-many-ways-to-say-and-in-japanese), but none of these words seem to quite fit the nuance I'm trying to forget. I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use あと, それと or それから for that.

(Incidentally, what connects sentences is not only te-forms but conjunctive forms in general including te-forms.)

Comment: What about それに?

Comment: Yes, you can use it too.