# can たら be translated as "because"?

Tags: grammar, usage, conjunctions

> 1. アイスクリームを食べたら、おなかがいたくなりました
> 2. コーヒーを飲んだら、ねられませんでした

In the above examples, can たら be translated as "because"? If not then why?

Comment: 1) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/verb-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-always-have-ambiguous-meanings

   2)  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0-etc

Comment: @A.Ellett:  [Comments are not for answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).

Answer (score 2):

たら is a conditional, it does not imply cause like 'because' would.

If you wanted to imply cause, then you would write:

アイスクリームを食べるとおなかがいたくなります。

or

アイスクリームを食べたからおなかがいたくなりました。

The way to use たら is for hypothetical situations or suggestions:

あついなー。アイスクリームたべたら？

アイスクリームたべたらからだがひえてくるかな？

Answer (score 0):

> (1) アイスクリームを食べたら、おなかがいたくなりました
>   In the above examples, can たら be translated as "because"? If not then why?

(0)アイスクリームを**食べたとき**、おなかがいたくなりました。
(1)**アイスクリームを食べたら、おなかがいたくなりました。**
(2)アイスクリームを**食べると**、おなかがいたくなりました。
(3)アイスクリームを**食べたから**、おなかがいたくなりました。

Translations are only for reference.
(0) **When** I ate the ice cream my stomach began to hurt.
(1) On condition that I ate the ice cream my stomach began to hurt.
(2) Same as above
(3) **Because** I ate the ice cream my stomach began to hurt.

In A. Ellett's comment, he/she said "it isn't explaining anything more than "when" does in english as in "when i ate the ice cream my stomach began to hurt".

But, when I think about the nuance of (1) and (2) **in Japanese**, they have the nuance between (0) and (3).
So, "たら" in the sentence (1) somewhat has a nuance of "because".

Comment: In this sense I would be more inclined to use your examples (0) and (3) because using your example (1) in this way doesn't make good sense in my head, even though I know it's correct.