# Help with the grammar だと and なるみたい

Tags: grammar, particle-と

So, I was reading a manga, and this sentence came up:

> 今日予報だと暑くなるみたいだよ。

I translated it as:

> It looks like it's going to become hot with today's forecast.

There are a few questions I'd like to ask:
What's だと、in this sentence? 

First I thought it meant `according to,` but when I searched around they said, `if or when.` 

 Like, `If you have today's forecast, it's going to be hot.` But does that mean something like, `If you're looking at today's forecast, it's going to be hot,` or something completely different?

Did I translate the `it's going to be hot` well?

Comment: I notice you edited the question title, but not the text. みたいだ is a more colloquial version of ようだ. It means 'it seems like'/'it looks like' etc. So 暑くなるみたいだ would be 'It looks like it will get hot'. You'd add this because you can't be certain it will get hot; weather forecasts are not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

だと might not specifically represent the idea of "according to", but I think "According to the forecast, it's going to get hot today (apparently)." would be an acceptable translation.

possible duplicate of [What does the だと mean in 日本だと?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/what-does-the-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8-mean-in-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8)

Comment: `According to today's forecast...` -- Hm.. are you aware that 今日 modifies 暑くなる, not 予報? Parse it 「今日、（予報だと）暑くなるみたいだよ」, "According to the forecast, it seems like it will be hot *today* ." (not 「今日**の**予報だと...」)

Comment: ah, so it could also be thought of as 今日は予報だと暑くなるみたいだよ。Thanks, I see what you're saying.