# Is と also a nominalizer? 「彼は本を手に取るとまた読み続けた」「家を出るとすぐに雨が降り始めた」

Tags: particle-と

I found a couple of examples where と (and not こと) seems to serve as a nominalizer.

(Segmentation is mine)

> 彼は本を手に取る**と**また読み続けた。
>
> 人は生まれる**と**直ぐ死に始める。
>
> 家を出る**と**直ぐに雨が降り始めた。

Is と a nominalizer?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32435/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14465/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28592/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This と is a particle conjunction that expresses a conditional. It's usually translated as "if" or "when" in English. It doesn't have anything to do with nouns.