# Expressing 'if so'

Tags: grammar

> 暇（なら・としたら）ちょっと手伝って下さい。
>   Hima (nara/toshitara) chotto tetsudatte kudasai.

Both the options seem grammatically correct.

Is it not so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

暇としたら is not grammatically correct. と here is related to the quoting particle and for quoting a sentence, you want a full sentence, here 暇だ *hima da*, giving 暇だとしたら *hima **da** to shitara*. In any case, I think the next two options are better choices of saying "if you have time / if you're free"

1. > 暇なら、ちょっと手伝ってください。
   >   *hima nara, chotto tetsudatte kudasai*

   which is correct just the way you said it.
2. > 暇だったら、ちょっと手伝ってください。
   >   *hima dattara, chotto tetsudatte kudasai*
   >
   > 暇 **でしたら**、ちょっと手伝ってください。
   >   *hima **deshitara**, chotto tetsudatte kudasai* (polite)

I myself would probably use the second one, although choosing between them would depend on the situation.

We have a question explaining the differences between なら, ～たら and ～えば:
[Differences among -たら、なら、-んだったら、-えば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-etc)

Comment: I disagree that と is the quotation particle here; it's the "as"/supposition particle.

Comment: @istrasci Hmm... I only know one name for と when it works like this grammatically. It's called "as"/supposition particle?

Comment: @Earthlin:  the "as" can be seen often in the form 〜として (「〜の資格で」; see examples in [definition #1 here](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6?dic=daijirin&oid=DJR_tosite_-010)).  The supposition/assumption case can be seen in [ex. 815 here](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=tosuru).