# How do you translate 作ってみたら in 妹がチーズドックを作ってみたら兄がwwww?

Tags: verbs, て-form, conditionals

It would seem to me the sentence says "little sister makes cheese dokku (whatever that food is) and .. big brother ... ?

I can't understand 作ってみたら . Is みたら the tara conditional form of 見る? Is it another thing? By intuition I would guess he's trying to say that she makes the cheese dokku and he uploads it to internet (youtube) to be seen? perhaps? but I can't make literally sense of the phrase. If みたら is a verb in conditional form, which verb it is and how does it fit in the sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "verb＋て＋みる" and "verb＋(よ)う+とする"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/what-is-the-difference-between-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%a6%ef%bc%8b%e3%81%bf%e3%82%8b-and-verb%ef%bc%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

Comment: ok, so  みた means tried and did something but what is that "ら" at the end? isnt  みた and not みたら the example linked?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30516/5010

Comment: Can you combine if + tried?  Does that semantically makes sense? How would it be the whole sentenece translation, "if she tried to do cheese dokku" ( like if he didnt know if she did it or not?) But the guy actually knows she did it, because it's in the video he recorded?

Comment: Did you read the two answers in the link? This question may be better: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56156/5010

Comment: Yes I did. But I dont understand how everything fits together. If I understood right, one says みた it's like saying tried to do something. And the other says ら adds conditional "if" to the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`te-form + みる` is "to try ～ing" or "to ～ (and see what happens)". This みる is a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010).

- [What is the difference between "verb＋て＋みる" and "verb＋(よ)う+とする"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19038/5010)

みたら is the "past conditional" form of みる, but this form often just means "when" or "and".

- [Differences among -たら、なら、-んだったら、-えば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/5010)

  > Use like ～と to show a sequential, cause-and-effect relationship between the two clauses
- [How to know if ～たら is hypothetical or temporal](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56156/5010)

  > In these examples, the たら verb happened and caused the main verb
- [Other uses of the たら conditional](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30516/5010)

  > While it is a 'conditional' it has a broader meaning than just 'if'.

Therefore:

妹がチーズドッグを作る。
My sister makes a cheese dog.

妹がチーズドッグを作ってみる。
My sister **tries** mak**ing** a cheese dog.

妹がチーズドッグを作ってみた。
My sister tri**ed** making a cheese dog.

妹がチーズドッグを作ってみたら、…
**When** my sister tried making a cheese dog, ...
My sister made a cheese dog (as a test/practice), **and** ...