# 帰宅すれば、必ずお風呂に入りなさい。'When you get home, be absolutely sure to take a bath' Why is this an incorrect usage of ~Ba?

Tags: conditionals

× 帰宅すれば、必ずお風呂に入りなさい。Why is this incorrect? Is it because it is non-volitional? takes out the decision aspect?

Comment: see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/22352

Comment: related? : https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25569/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28354/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ば only works as action and consequence. A common example given is "if you drop a ball, it will fall". You can't put a command, volition, etc, after ば, but rather a sequence of events; the result (ball falling) after the action (dropping the ball). And ば doesn't have a meaning of "when" either, and even translating as "if" would not make for natural English either at times. Like この通りを行けば病院につく. Again, action and consequence; go down this path and you will arrive at the hospital.

Answer (score 3):

> When you get home, be absolutely sure to take a bath.
>   A : 帰宅**すれば**、必ずお風呂に入りなさい。
>   B : 帰宅し**たら**、必ずお風呂に入りなさい。

Jisho.org defines them as:

> #### すれば
>
> Expression
>   1. if so; in that case; in that situation​

and

> #### たら
>
> Conjunction, Particle
>   1. indicates supposition; if ... then; when; after​
>   あ、とりあえず包帯{ほうたい}しているけど、もし煩｛わずら｝わしかっ**たら**、家｛うち｝に帰｛かえ｝ってからカットバンに代｛か｝えても大丈夫｛だいじょうぶ｝よ。
>   Ah, well I've bandaged it for the meantime but if that's awkward then it's fine to replace it with a plaster **when** you get home.