# What does 間違っていたら、修正してください mean, particularly ～ていたら?

Tags: translation, words, verbs, conjugations

間違っていたら、修正してください。

I don't understand the word いたら after the verb in -TE form.

Thank you

Comment: It's just the [-たら conditional form](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/) of いる "to be/exist".

Answer (score 4):

間違っていたら、修正してください。

- 間違う means "to make a mistake"
- 間違って is the て form of 間違う
- 間違っている means "are/is making a mistake"
- 間違っていた is the た form of 間違っている and means "were/was making a mistake"
- 間違っていたら means "if I was making a mistake"

Comment: You are having the wrong subject for the first part of the sentence. It cannot be `you`. It is either `it` or `I`, the `you` is the subject of the second part though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the past conditional with -ている. Here are two good resources that will allow you to understand this grammar form and anything similar to it:

http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/teform
http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/conditionals

Friendly Ghost described the deconstruction of the meaning very well in his answer. In general, you can recognize the above intuitively as:

て-form + いる --> enduring state of verb (i.e. 食べている -> eating)

て-form + いた --> past enduring state of verb (i.e. 食べていた -> was eating)

て-form + いたら --> past enduring state of verb with conditional (i.e. 食べていたら -> if was eating)

So this sentence means something along the lines of: "If you were making a mistake, please correct it." I think the subject of the sentence is up for debate since there's not really any context. Hope this helps!