# What is the meaning of と here?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-と

What is the meaning of と in this sentence?

> このため、地震のときと同じように机の下などに入っている**と**安全なことがあります。

It seems different from all senses in *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar*. Kind of "in the manner of"?

Answer (score 2):

`と` here means `when`. It's a conditional (A と B), where B naturally follows from A. See [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-etc).

The sentence as a whole reads like:

> Because of this, it will be safe **when** you hide under a desk like you would during an earthquake.