# なら or たら - what is the difference when saying “if”

Tags: grammar

I am still a bit confused as to when to use なら or たら in a sentence for an “if.....” question.

For examaple, if I want to say - “if there is a problem, please speak English” - what would be the most correct:

もし問題あるなら英語で話してください

Or

もし問題あったら英語で話してください﻿

And what would be the difference?

Thank you..

N.

Comment: Check this question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-etc