# Is it grammatically correct to use もし and/or 〜ば form along with the 〜たい form to convey desire in a conditional clause?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

My impression when using conditionals, most of the time, you lose the ability to express desire. For example, when conjugating to -たら、you have to use the past tense of the verb. Is it grammatically correct to use もし or ば form to convey desire in conditional?

> **もし**公園に行きたいんですが、電話して下さい。

or

> 公園に行きた**ければ**、電話して下さい。

Comment: No you don't lose the ability to express desire. もし can be used with たい and ば, but your first example will have to be revised to something like:  **もし**公園に行き**たい**のであれ**ば**、電話してください。
There is a very comprehensive answer discussing all these conditionals [here.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0-etc)

Comment: Who says you can't conjugate all conditional forms on たい? You can have any of たければ、たいのなら、たかったら.

Comment: Excuse me, what are you trying to say by 「もし公園に行きたいんですが、電話して下さい。」 ? Can you add the English translation?

Answer (score 1):

行きたければ is not past tense. It comes directly form 行きたい.

iku (行く) to go
iki-masu (行きます) to go
iki-tai (行きたい) want to go
iki-takereba (行きたければ) if you want to go

行きたい comes from 行きます by replacing "masu" with "tai".
行きたければ comes from 行きたい by replacing "i" with "kereba".

You can use もし to reinforce the conditional. The use of もし in this case is optional.

もし行きたければ
If you want to go.

There are other ways to express conditionals.
For example you can use なら:

もし公園に行きたいなら、電話して下さい。

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's grammatically correct to use もし and/or 〜ば form along with the 〜たい form to convey desire in a conditional clause.

But が in もし公園に行きたいんですが、電話して下さい。 is wrong.