# Should I use と or たら in that case?

Tags: usage, nuances, conditionals

I've got a task in uni today to put either と or たら. And there's a sentence I can't comprehend:
箸で食べて（みると、みたら）どうですか。
I don't quite understand which form I have to use here, so it would be great if I could find some help!

Comment: と cannot be used when making suggestions/invitations.

Comment: Also see this answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0-etc/1784#1784

Answer (score 2):

食べてみるとどうですか
食べたあとの感想を聞きたいという感じ

食べてみたらどうですか
食べるのを試しませんかという感じ