# General conditional (-えば form) expressing something without supposition or back thought?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I found a resource which says the *-eba* form is a form used to express a conditional without supposition or back thought.

I didn't find any others resources that spoke about the same thing. Is this a mistake in my resource or is it real ?

Is there another conditional form to specifically express something conditional but with a supposition or a back thought ?

I also found this useful post for [Differences among -たら、なら、-んだったら、-えば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-etc) but it doesn't help my case.

Edit : If someone is French, here is the link of [JLPT-Go](http://jlptgo.com/grammaire/60-japonais-conditionnel-general) (the ressource which says that)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "back thought"?

Comment: An ulterior motive : like when someone say something, you believe that they have a hidden reason for doing it/saying it

Comment: I have not heard of this specific nuance of the -eba form. If you give us a specific example sentence it might help, however.

Comment: Very vague question

Comment: I have edited my post with the link of my ressource, if it can help ! I am learning this conditionnal form, and I don't want to write something false, so it's why I asked this question and why it seams "vague"

Comment: @Karakayn Without their additional explanation, people have to judge that they misunderstands something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the explanation given in the link and it may be confusing to state it like this. In fact, the 「~えば」conditional form suppose no constraint on the context and is the most "open" conditional form. It implies that the condition (sentence in えば) is less probable to happen compared to the other conditional form but, if it went to happen (no matter how low are the odds), the action described in the second sentence would happen too. The emphasis is more on the fact that the condition is hard to meet. Examples :

- もしよかったら ==> If you agree/if you're fine
- もしよければ ==> Same meaning but sounds more hypothetical than the first one, implying that you're requesting something more rude/asking for a favor that burden a lot the person you're speaking to