# Use of やと in 「日本人やとそれが当たり前やから、いまいちわからない」？

Tags: grammar, particles, kansai-ben

I understand や = だ in Kansai-ben but I don’t understand what either やと or だと would mean here. I’m guessing the meaning is close to “For Japanese people that is normal so I don’t understand.” Thanks!!!

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%20%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%20

Answer (score 3):

This や/だ is a copula, and と is a condition marker ("if/when"). See: [Differences among -たら、なら、-んだったら、-えば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/393/5010)

Therefore this 日本人だと is interchangeable with 日本人だったら or 日本人なら. A more literal translation would be "if it were (the case of) Japanese", but your translation is also fine.