# I can't recognize which conditional form to use?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, particles

so as you know there are varieties of conditions forms in Japanese...(と, …ば, …たら, なら)
*and 大変ですね？*
so my problem is, I may be able to recognize them in a test but while speaking, I have no idea which to use or how to use (they confuse me )
if I want to write in my diary (in Japanese ) I again have this problem and then i get help with kind, dear google translate !!!
*so I would really appreciate it if you help me.
thanks for reading*

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific on what your problem is. Maybe this link helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0-etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences among -たら、なら、-んだったら、-えば, etc](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89-%e3%82%93%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-%e3%81%88%e3%81%b0-etc)