# What is the difference between the conditionals なら & ば?

Tags: particles

Examples:

なら：
みんなが行くなら私も行く

ば：
楽しくなければ、私も行かない

What is the difference between the two?
なら says it's used to represent what will happen in a given context. ば says there is no condition. I understand と (natural consequence) but I don't understand the need for a distinction between なら & ば.

tldr;
what would be the difference between
みんなが行くなら私も行く
&
みんなが行けば私も行く
Google translate says both mean "if everyone goes, I'll go."

Comment: 行くば doesn't make sense; you want 行けば

Comment: mate translator (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mate-translate-%E2%80%93-translat/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke) doesn't seem to make a distinctions between them either (the tldr; sentences).

Comment: I don't know no much about Japanese, so I'm not familiar with the verb conjugations. I was just using that as an example with the 2 conditional particles, but I'll fix it.

Comment: check out https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1784

Comment: Thanks @A.Ellett