# Particle と function in "あんまりのりだすとあぶないぞー"

Tags: particles, particle-と

A small doubt, in the phrase: "あんまりのりだすとあぶないぞー" I do not understand why the particle と is in the phrase, its function is not to include anything? As in lists etc? What function is she performing in that sentence?  I’m reading the manga Yotsubato and I came up with this question...

Comment: Are you familiar with the conditional と?

Comment: Apologies for removing your Portuguese, but [I believe questions are only allowed to be in English or Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22/78).

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese Language Stack Exchange! This is a great question, but there are already answers on the site that may help you with it. Please follow the link I'll paste at the end of this comment and see if the relevant parts of Derek Schaab's answer clear things up for you. (In particular, look at the third example in the "と、ば" section of his answer, "早く行かないと、遅刻します".) And if it doesn't help, maybe you could revise your question to make it more specific. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-たら-なら-と-んだったら-ば-etc